# Set height of select2

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

How to increase the *height* of the select2 suggestion dropdown?

I tried the idea proposed at https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/144:

```
.select2-results {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

However, that does not work. If I instead set the `min-height` property, the size is increased, however, I do not want to have a 500px huge dropdown if there are only 1 or 2 items...so `min-height` is not really an option.

I want the dropdown to dynamically adjust its height to the content, but increase its height up to 500px before a scrollbar is displayed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use:

```
.select2-results__options {
   max-height: 500px;
}
```

If that doesn't work try to add `!important` so it overwrite it's default max-height (try both methods, yours and mine).

Comment: Yep, thanks, my overwrite was more general than the default set in the Select2 CSS. I didn't use `!important` but instead made my selector more specific, but you got me thinking into the right direction!

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers above worked for me, but this did. I'm putting it here for future reference on google :

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results > .select2-results__options {
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set both the `.select2-drop` and `.select2-results` classes as follows:

```
.select2-drop {
    max-height: /* Your value here */;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.select2-results {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

This ensures that the results are not limited in height and that the dropdown is still usable. If you test it you should see that it works for variable list lengths no matter how you set the max-height on `.select2-drop`. Shorter lists should fit content and long lists should scroll within that limit.